# Достать ASIN из ссылки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url

есть задача парсить товары с амазон. 
Необходимо сделать сверку на уникальность товара, чтобы не было дублей, решил это делать по ASIN - уникальный ид товара.

Так вот нужно достать этот параметр из ссылки

[https://www.amazon.com/L-L-Surprise-Boys-Surprises/dp/B07PRZYJHT/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_19?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YEFMY90WBT8QPMJ22H8W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PRZYJHT)

где - B07PRZYJHT - это ASIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASIN - это всегда 10 буквоцифр. В URL он всегда обрамлён слэшами. Так что по этому признаку и будем идентифицировать. И шаблон будет

```
\/(\w{10})($|\/)
```

Т.е. слэш, затем строго 10 цифр/букв, затем слэш либо конец строки.

Answer (score -2):

```
$str='https://www.amazon.com/L-L-Surprise-Boys-Surprises/dp/B07PRZYJHT/ref=zg_bs_toys-and-games_19?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YEFMY90WBT8QPMJ22H8W';

$arr=explode("/", $str);

print_r($arr[5]);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    # code...
$str1 = strlen($value);
if($str1=='10'){
    echo $value;
}

}
```

Comment: он уже убрал слово регулярка, хватит  ставить минусы )

Comment: Всё, что не описано явно, может быть как угодно. Поэтому нигде не задокументированный факт, что именно пятый элемент URL всегда будет ASIN, в общем взят с потолка. Это, вероятно, и вызывает негатив... К тому же слово "регулярка" убрал не автор, см. кто именно откорректировал.

Comment: @Akina сделал условие if($str1=='10') как вы и говорили )

Comment: Если ASIN пятый - вставленная проверка не нужна. Но если нет? тогда она бесполезна - значение-то в массиве есть, но оно не будет выведено... Да и  говорил я не о проверке...

Comment: @Akina там foreach отдельно стоит, из всего массива эл выдирает там где 10 англ символов

Comment: Ну это тебе просто повезло, что `http://amazon.com/` переадресует на `http://www.amazon.com/`... а в принципе есть потенция ошибки, ибо проверять только длину - мало. А проверять каждый элемент массива на шаблон коллбэком, наверное, расточительно.